# How do I stack queries using Active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to stack or join multiple queries to the same model.

For instance, I have these two queries:

```
@query1 = User.where(:survey_response => params[:survey_response])
@query2 = User.where(:profile => params[:profile])
```

How can I execute `@query1.@query2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ActiveRecord::SpawnMethods#merge`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge) for that:

```
@query1.merge(@query2)
# SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."survey_response" = "foo" AND "users"."profile" = "bar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would create a new method in the User model. For example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def survey_response
    where(:survey_response => params[:survey_response])
  end

  def profile
    where(:profile => params[:profile])
  end
end
```

You can also chain them in a method:

```
def profile_and_user_reponse
  where(:profile => params[:profile])
    .where(:survey_response => params[:survey_response])
end
```

Or just call `<User>.survey_response.profile`